# Scale image to fill multiple pages with iText

Tags: itext, pdf-generation, scaling

I am trying to scale an image with iText (on a new PDF document) in order to make it fill the width of the page without streching, so that it could take several pages.

I've found a lot of solutions but they were pretty complicated and I don't really like coding like that. The best solution I've found till now (from another question on SO) is using PdfTable but it always uses a single page, scaling the image.

```
// Load image from external storage
Image image = Image.getInstance(path + "/img.png");
// Calculate ratio
float width = PageSize.A4.getWidth();
float heightRatio = image.getHeight() * width / image.getWidth();
Document document = new Document();
document.open();
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);
table.setWidthPercentage(100);
PdfPCell c = new PdfPCell(image, true);
c.setBorder(PdfPCell.NO_BORDER);
c.setPadding(0);
// Set image dimensions
c.getImage().scaleToFit(width, heightRatio);
table.addCell(c);
document.add(table);
// Write PDF file
document.close();
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: In PDF each page has its own canvas. If the image is drawn on one page canvas, this only can influence the appearance of that very page, it has no effect on others. What you can do is draw the same image on multiple pages with appropriately chosen image positions. image position

Comment: Thanks @Bruno, I see. I am trying to solve the problem that way right now. I have also found this answer of yours http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-show-image-large-dimensions-across-multiple-pages (at least I assume by the picture it was you ;)).

Comment: The comment was provided by @mkl but you're right the guy in the picture is me and the woman right next to me is my wife ;-) Does that example solve your problem? It's not that complex, is it?

Comment: No @Bruno it's not, I just was hopeing to do it in a cleaner way. In the answer below my solution, based on that very one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok I finally decided to go the way I didn't want to go, since it seems to be the only way: adding the same image to every page and setting the proper vertical offset to each one. The offset gets calculated as the number of pages left to draw + the gap the remains blank. For each step I decrement the number of pages until there's nothing left to draw.

```
// Open new PDF file
Document document = new Document();
PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(getSharedDirPath() + File.separator + "file.pdf"));

document.open();
PdfContentByte content = pdfWriter.getDirectContent();

// Load image from external folder
Image image = Image.getInstance(path + "/img.png");
image.scaleAbsolute(PageSize.A4);
image.setAbsolutePosition(0, 0);

float width = PageSize.A4.getWidth();
float heightRatio = image.getHeight() * width / image.getWidth();
int nPages = (int) (heightRatio / PageSize.A4.getHeight());
float difference = heightRatio % PageSize.A4.getHeight();

while (nPages >= 0) {
    document.newPage();
    content.addImage(image, width, 0, 0, heightRatio, 0, -((--nPages * PageSize.A4.getHeight()) + difference));
}

// Write PDF file
document.close();
```

Honestly I don't like this solution, I thought it was possible to auto-adjust dimensions as I do in a text editor, but after all it was not very difficult.....it just took me three days to figure out how the whole PDF thing worked.

Comment: *Honestly I don't like this solution* - there is no reason not to.

Comment: Of course there's not. "De gustibus non disputandum est".

Comment: *there is no reason to* in the sense of *there is no fundamentally better way to do it*

Comment: I use the `scaleToFit()` method to scale an image in one dimension whilst keeping the aspect ratio intact. For instance, in your case, I'd do: `image.scaleToFit(PageSize.A4.getWidth(), 10000);` By using an extremely large value in the `y` direction, the image will scale in the `x` direction and the height will be adapted accordingly, preserving the aspect ratio.

Comment: yeah mkl, I got it, I first thought there was a "better" way. @Bruno I will try that. Anyway I think it is useless since I have to set width and height manually in the addImage call, isn't it?